# LaTeX flow chart error

Tags: nodes, flow-charts

Why is the position of my 9th node not right? I try to change the flow chart but I get a compile time error:

[image: result]

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.4cm] % hiệu chỉnh khoảng cách giữa các node
        \small
        \node (io) [startstop] {Begin};
        \node (1) [io, below of=io] {Nhận dữ liệu tọa độ nugời dùng \(i\)};
        \node (2) [process, below of=1,yshift=-0.5cm] {Dùng hàm kmeans chia thành i cụm (i=minicum,...
        ..,maxicum)};
        \node (3) [process, below of =2] { Nhận được tọa độ i UAV cụm và sumd};     
        \node (4) [process, below of=3] {sum\_dist 
            = sum(sumd)};
        \node (5) [process, below of=4] {sum\_dist2
            =sum(d)};
        \node (6) [process,  below of=5]{obj=sum\_dist
            +sum\_dist2};
        \node (7) [decision,  below of=6] {i=
        maxicum};
        \node (8) [process, below of=7] {Tìm min của obj};
        \node (9) [process, right of 8] {obj};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lưu đồ giải thuật để số UAV cụm }
\label{fig:timUAVcANN}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! You forgot add`=` sign: Correct is ` \node (9) [process, right of = 8] {obj};`.

Comment: thanks forget that

Comment: Does works now as you like? BTW, your code fragment cannot be tested since you not provide definitions of nodes styles. Please, always provide complete, compilable document, which reproduce your problem. Also code for your flowchart can be simpler and shorter by use of `chains` and `positioning` libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You may liked the following way of drawing of the your flowchart:

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
      start chain = A going below,
       arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
%
      base/.style = {draw, semithick, text width=44mm, minimum height=8mm,
                     align=center, font=\small},
 startstop/.style = {base, rounded corners},   
   process/.style = {base},                  
        io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                     trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
  decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=2, inner xsep=-3pt},
  every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\small}       
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   [startstop] {Begin};            % A-1
\node   [io]        {Nhận dữ liệu tọa độ nugời dùng \(i\)};
\node   [process]   {Dùng hàm kmeans chia thành i cụm (i=minicum,\dots , maxicum)};
\node   [process]   {Nhận được tọa độ i UAV cụm và sumd};
\node   [process]   {sum\_dist = sum(sumd)};
\node   [process]   {sum\_dist2 =sum(d)};
\node   [process]   {obj=sum\_dist +sum\_dist2};
\node   [decision]  {i = maxicum};
\node   [process]   {Tìm min của obj};    % A-8
    \end{scope}
\node (A-10) [process, right=of A-8] {obj};
% arrows not drawn by join macro
\path        (A-8) to ["Y"]     (A-9);
\draw[arr]   (A-8) to ["N" ']   (A-10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]